# Using OpenID to log in to different domains

Tags: web, openid

I have the domain `example.com`, which supports OpenID log in.

I want change the domain name to `example.net`.

Now the people registered at `example.com` with OpenID cannot log in to `example.net` with their existing accounts. Instead, they will be registered as new users.

So, does OpenID have some technique to solve this problem?

Comment: Specific to Google's implementation: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/googles-openids-are-unique-per-domain/

Answer (score 0):

Most OpenID providers will provide the same identifier to all sites. The only major exception is Google. However, Google will provide the e-mail address if you ask it to, so you can join the accounts that way. That's what StackExchange does. (Note that Google e-mail addresses may be `@gmail.com` or `@googlemail.com`, so check just on the first part.)